# Extent of ARCore feature support in Google Pixel 5

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

I have been unable to find a list of supported features on mobile devices any more detailed than [this](https://developers.google.com/ar/devices).

I am trying to find the ideal phone for an ARCore-based proof of concept I am working on. I have noticed that some phones support certain features only partially. E.g. a Moto G9 plus will deliver only a partial lighting estimation at times.

Does anyone know of a way to determine beforehand to which extent a given phone supports ARCore – without having to buy the phone to find out?

I am particularly interested in the Google Pixel 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds really weird but the Google Pixel 5 doesn't have a ToF sensor for Scene Reconstruction in ARCore. Instead it relies on the wide and ultra-wide lenses for depth estimation (using a Depth-from-Motion algorithm) inside new Depth API. No comments.

I would take a closer look at phones like [Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultra](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s20_ultra_5g-10040.php). It supports not only Depth API's software Depth-from-Motion algorithm, but also Time-of-Flight hardware depth sensor.

Nonetheless, both gadgets support the same [set of features](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/quickstart) found in ARCore 1.25.